# Need advice on writing iOS apps on iPad with Swift Playgrounds

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, ipad-playgrounds

I want to write a keyboard app for iOS, but I only have an iPad at my disposal at the moment. I've been searching Apple Developer documentation as well as online forums and I'm not finding the answers I need to get started. There is focused documentation on Apple Developer (see: [Creating a custom keyboard](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/keyboards_and_input/creating_a_custom_keyboard)) that pertains to xcode and selecting the `Custom Keyboard Extension` template, but I'm not seeing this in Playgrounds. This makes me think I may have to build the app from the ground up, and I have no experience with Swift or app development.

Does anyone have any advice on how I can get started?

Out of my comfort zone,
-Kristopher

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you will need to use Xcode on a Mac to do this.  Playgrounds are not a full replacement for Xcode.

The ability to publish an app from a playground is relatively new and is limited.

To create a custom keyboard you need to combine an app with a custom keyboard extension in one project. Playgrounds can't do this.

Comment: That's a bummer. Thanks for the quick reply!